# Trinket M0 - Using USB serial out when running on battery

Tags: usb, serial, low-battery

I am using a Trinket M0 for navigation lights on an electric R/C plane. I thought it would be useful to also use it to monitor my LiPo voltage so I know if it is safe for another flight. For debugging, I'd like to be able to output the current voltage via the serial monitor. But if my USB cable is connected for the monitor, then the battery is not in use. Can I accomplish this by snipping the 5v line from a USB cable?

Comment: please ask about the problem, not about your solution to the problem

Answer (score 1):

USB data connections can be established without using the power supply line.

I verified this with a modified USB cable, that has the 5 V wire cut in two.